# how to figure out which build options CMake may have?

Tags: cmake, build-system

${SUBJECT}, but let me explain it a little bit more. I am big autotools fan, and there are no problems with autotools options definition, everything is written in the `configure.ac` file through either `AC_ARG_WITH` or `AC_ARG_ENABLE`, but CMake projects usualli have few `CMakeList.txt` files ( in the subsirs), and I am confused what should I look for to find which build options CMake might have.

EDIT: or is is also possible to see `./configure --help` after autoconf worked properly for autotools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cmake-gui` (QT GUI) or `ccmake` (console UI) utilities are user-friendly ways to look up configurable options.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `CMakeCache.txt` file in your build directory after running `cmake`.  This is where settings are stored.